# How to restrict to access to non-SEO URLs in Joomla 3?

Tags: url, joomla, seo, friendly-url

I've converted all my URLs to SEO friendly URLs.
But I want to restrict to be accessed to my non-seo friendly URLs.
As an example, you can access to www.example.com/article-1 with http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=76&Itemid=113. But I don't want this. I just want you to be able to access with http://www.example.com/article-1

I wish that I'm clear to explain what I need.

Comment: The link is not working plus it's not clear what you would like to achieve.

Comment: As you see, the link is just as an example, I just wanted to restrict the second link to be accessible. If you activate joomla SEF URLs, you can access any article with SEF url and non SEF url. But I don't want the article to be accessible by non SEF URLs. Did you get it now? I think it is more clear now.

Comment: You could restrict non-SEF links it in htaccess, but what's the point? If non-SEF links won't be published anywhere, nobody will be using them.

Comment: I just want my site looks totaly SEF URLs. I don't want someone to use my non-SEF URLs, If he want to use my website, he should use SEF URLs. So what should I add to .htaccess for this?

And by the way, I'm not publishing non-SEF URLs but google is indexing them. So If someone access my site over google and find a good article, when he wants to share I don't want him to send non-SEF URL to his friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible for the simple reason that Joomla always uses the non-SEF links internally. That's why they always work.
Also there are links which are not converted to SEF links because the user will not see and Google will not index them. Like links used by AJAX scripts or similar things.

If you block non-SEF urls in your .htaccess file, expect your page to break sooner than later. Don't blame the extension developer then :-)

Comment: It is of course possible with mod_rewrite, but will break Joomla, as you say in your second paragraph. Would vote up, if you corrected the first sentence accordingly.

Comment: If it's not possible without breaking Joomla, then I'd say it's not possible :-)